# Cant run existing android project on eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have copied the workspace for android on my hard disk and setup up a fresh Windows XP. Then after i set up Java, Android and Eclipse, I imported the project into Eclipse with File->new project-> Existing android project. But when I am trying to run it, it's showing the following  error

```
[2013-09-06 13:33:39 - p112] Android Launch!
[2013-09-06 13:33:39 - p112] adb is running normally.
[2013-09-06 13:33:39 - p112] Could not find p112.apk!
```

What to do?

Comment: I suppose you already succeeded in cleaning and building the project?

Comment: yes. i did it atleast now. But still showing the error.

Comment: Does it build compile ok? Any errors shown? Also see the problems view in Eclipse `Window` -> `Show View` -> `Problems`

Comment: What exactly did you do at the import? I cannot repeat the steps, you mentioned (File->New Project-> ...), since I don't have "Existing Android Project" there. Usually use should use _File->Import->Existing Project_ into Workspace to import a project.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your project is not build and apk file is not generated for it.

Check in your bin folder if apk file exists there!

Try Building your project and then run it.

Comment: SdkControllerApp.apk is the only apk file found in 'C:\android-sdk\tools\apps\SdkController\bin'

Comment: It has nothing to do with your SDK directory. bin folder, which holds apk and some other resources after building your project, should be located inside your project directory.

Comment: check in your project directory bin folder.